# chain and mix express router (.route) and (.get, .post .. etc) methods

Tags: javascript, express

I've the following code structure

```
let router = require( 'express' ).Router();
```

and later on I define my route(s) as follows:

```
router
    .route( '/' )
    .get( listMiddleware );

router
    .route( '/:id' )
    .get( getOneByIdMiddleware );
```

When I tried to optimize my code and remove the unnecessary second router call (from my point of view) like the following, it didn't work!

```
router
    .route( '/' )
    .get( listMiddleware )
    .route( '/:id' )
    .get( getOneByIdMiddleware );
```

I got this TypeError

```
TypeError: router.route(...).get(...).route is not a function
```

the `.route()` is in the router prototype and I thought each router method  (like get, post .. etc) returns the router for further chaining (which is somehow true in the working example).

What exactly I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `router.route()` doesn't return the *router* instance, it returns a *route* instance, which has chainable `.get()/.post()/...` methods, but not `.route()`.

You can find the implementation of `router.route()` [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/9f019c8c6966736803a65eb4a96d0e7e87e85ede/lib/router/index.js#L478-L504), if you're interested.